# Update Mac binaries on Ubuntu server with tlmgr (TeX Live 2011)

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, mactex, updating

How can I update the Mac binaries of a TeX Live installation on a Ubuntu server?

The setup is the following:

- I have a headless Ubuntu 11.10 server running on which I have
  installed TeX Live 2011. More specifically, I have installed the
  Linux (`x86_64-linux`), Mac (`x86_64-darwin`) and Windows (`win32`)
  binaries.
- I can access the server via `ssh` from my local network.
- I want to update the Mac part of the distribution.

I can update the Linux binaries without hassle, as I am naturally able to execute the `tlmgr` within the `x86_64-linux` folder. If I connect to the server via `ssh` and try to run `tlmgr` from the `x86_64-darwin` directory I get an error, of course, because it is built for the wrong architecture.

If I run “TeX Live Utility” from the MacTeX package (with paths accordingly set), the GUI shows me “Listing failed” and the log file reads

```
2012-01-24 12:12:15 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][355]
tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
tlmgr: could not find a usable wget.
tlmgr: Please install wget and try again.
tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
```

How can I get `tlmgr` to work correctly?

Comment: Are you saying that a `tlmgr update --all` does _not_ also update the Mac and Windows binaries?

Comment: Hm, maybe it does. Actually I have no idea of how `tlmgr` really works—I thought it just cared for the binaries of the same architecture, i. e. the Linux `tlmgr` only updates the Linux files. Is there any way I can find out whether `tlmgr` “knows” that there are other files which should be updated as well?

Comment: Try `tlmgr update --list`. And read `man tlmgr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear from your question how you installed the platforms. If `tlmgr platform list` shows all your intended platforms as installed, a simple `tlmgr update --all` should work. If it doesn't, you should install the platforms with `tlmgr platform add ...`

Of course these commands should be run on the server.

Comment: I installed via the Ubuntu `tl-install` routine. `tlmgr platform list` gives me: `Available platforms: x86_64-darwin, win32, x86_64-linux` so I guess that it should already be working the way I want it to. Thanks for the useful answer.