# XeLaTeX - Bottleneck at eu1enc.def

Tags: xetex, compiling, fontspec, profiling

With XeLaTeX my compiler always consistently slows down when it comes to accessing `eu1enc.def` (I am using the `fontspec` package). I tried with copying that file and the others employed at that point (`eu1lmr.fd`, `eu1lmss.fd`, `xunicode.sty`, `fontenc.sty`, `fontspec.cfg`) into the folder with the `.tex` file to be compiled, but there was no improvements in speed.

Do you have any suggestion to obtain faster results?

Comment: I doubt that finding and reading this file can be a bottleneck. Show a minimal example that demonstrates your problem and a screenshot that shows when xelatex slows down.

Comment: Do you have the full TeXLive distribution installed? I ran into this several times when I had installed only a small custom selection of packages. `eu1enc` is supposed to bundled with something else automatically. You can install it using `tlmgr`, or you can add it manually (there's a more complicated procedure using `texhash`). But it might be best just to install the full distribution.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewCashner. I have MiKTeX on my machine, but I tried several solutions in that direction (like installing a version with more packages, or passing precisely to TeX Live). My problem is that I am using a corporate computer and, not having admin rights, my hands are quite tied :P

Comment: In that case, do you absolutely need XeLaTeX and not pdfLaTeX? If you're using the Latin or Greek alphabets, you can do a lot by using UTF8 encoding and any of the font packages listed in the LaTeX font catalog.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes :( I need to use a certain font according to the firm policy.

Comment: What about setting up a portable LaTeX installation on a USB stick and using that to compile? (Or asking the administrator for a full installation, of course.)

Comment: Tried with a MiKTeX portable version, not working because of lacking packages :( Do you know how to install additional packages on a portable version without the Package Manager? I simply copied them from the "official" MiKTeX repository I should use, but somewhat they are not recognised.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with the font cache, see [Different compilation times with different Operating Systems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57204/3323).

Comment: If you need to use TeX and you have to use that font, then either they should install the software you need or they should give you the rights to do so yourself. Otherwise, it is like insisting on hard copy but refusing to give you any paper. What do they expect you to do? Failing that, I bet the policy doesn't say you have to use that font when compiling drafts, does it? Just use XeTeX and their font for the final version.